# EPplus LoadFromDataTable DateTime saved as Int

Tags: epplus

I am using the very nice LoadFromDataTable feature in EPplus4.0.1.  It saves DateTimes as Integers even although the DataTable column is DateTime.
Is there a fix for this as it causes problems when reading back into a DataTable which expects a DateTime.
Manually setting the sheet column to DateTime is not an option as loading happens in the code and I don't expect my users to know how to do it manually.

Answer (score 2):

Excel natively stores dates as numbers - you'll need to set the format of the cells to display their date values.

For example, if in your spreadsheet column C contains the dates, try the following:

```
MyWorksheet.Cells["C:C"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy"l
```

Comment: Yes, I have fixed it during the read like you suggested but I would have preferred to have it formatted by LoadFromDataTable as a DateTime. The DataTable knows it is DateTime and I wondered if there was any EPplus extension which does that.  I forsee problems with users if they look at the output spreadsheet and wonder where the date is